# Cant generate django template {# minimal comment #} in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, django-templates

I cannot configure my vscode for generate comments like this

```
{# comment here #}
```

just working this type of comment

```
{% comment %} comment here  {% endcomment %}
```

this is my vscode config
[image]

I already change to other keybindings but doesnt work